# htaccess rewriterule generating multiple copies of wrong match

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Trying to use prettyURLs rewritten to php param qrys using .htaccess rules.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^foo/?([^/]*)/?([^/]*)/?$  /foo.php?s=$1&c=$2 [NC,END,R=301,QSA]
RewriteRule ^bar/?([^/]*)/?$  /bar.php?s=$1 [NC,END,R=301,QSA]
```

The first rule works correctly, but the second one generates:
https://example.com/bar.php?s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=.php&s=45843

from
https://example.com/bar/45843

Comment: Do you have any more rules apart from these shown ones? Kindly do let us know

Comment: Not that I'm aware of, the only other code in that file is:

```
# BROWSER CACHING USING CACHE-CONTROL HEADERS
<ifModule mod_headers.c> 
    # One year for image and video files
    <filesMatch ".(flv|gif|ico|jpg|jpeg|mp4|mpeg|png|svg|swf|webp)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=31536000, public"
    </filesMatch>

    # One month for JavaScript and PDF files
    <filesMatch ".(js|pdf)$">
        Header set Cache-Control "max-age=2592000, public"
    </filesMatch>

    # One month for CSS files.....(etc)
</ifModule>
```

Answer (score 1):

`RewriteCond` directives are only applied to the *single* `RewriteRule` immediately following them. That means that your *second* `RewriteRule` is *not* covered by any `RewriteCond`. Which means it creates an endless rewriting loop.

You want to reject that, pointing out that you rewrite to `/bar.php` which is not matched *again* by the matching pattern maybe, but ...

That is not true actually. Take a closer look at your rule:

```
RewriteRule ^bar/?([^/]*)/?$  /bar.php?s=$1 [NC,END,R=301,QSA]
```

The matching pattern uses `/?` which makes the slash *optional* . So `bar.php?s=whatever` is *again* matched. In the next round the rewriting engine does.

Solution:

1. apply the conditions to *both* rules and
2. use a proper matching pattern.

Actually I am not sure what you are trying to match with those patterns ... Why the `/?`?

- Are you trying to match a query string that way? That won't work, you need another `RewriteCond` for that applyiong a matching pattern against `%{QUERY_STRING}`. That is documented, actually.
- Or are you trying to make anything after `/bar` *optional* ? Then use a pattern like `^/?bar(/[^/]*)?/?$` maybe ...

Comment: Applying the conditions to both rules seems to be working, will test more rigorously tomorrow. (I was certain that I tried that before resorting to StackOverflow, but must have been too tired to do implement and test it right.)

The optional slash at end of matching pattern is for adding an optional qry param in conjunction with the [QSA] tag.

Comment: It is important that you _understand_ what the issue is with that rule. The `/?` does not refer to the trailing ocurrence, but the first one, immediately following the `bar`.

Comment: And I completely fail to understand what matching a potential trailing slash should have to do with using the QSA flag.

Comment: Probably nothing, it may be more to handle both example.com/param1/param2 and example.com/param1/param2/ in the same way? Some people may type the URL in and add a slash.
I'm guessing QSA triggers off of a question mark only: (example.com/param1/param2?param3=value)

Comment: No, the QSA flag is perfectly fine to handle the query question mark all by itself. You apparently confuse the literal question mark in a URL and the semanticquestion mark in a matching pattern. Both have absolutely no conenction.